# Chrome Web Store: Public API for app/extension info retrieval

Tags: api, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store

The [Chrome Web Store API](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/webstore_api/items) allows you to perform a bunch of operations as an app/extension developer, for example uploading or updating an extension.

Is there an (unauthenticated) API that allows `GET`ting information about app/extensions, for example their publishing date or their version number?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that short of scrapping the pages, there isn't such a public API.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the extension/app installed on your device, you can use chrome.app.getDetails() in the console of that extension/app to retrieve a lot of the same information available in the Chrome Web Store. This isn't exactly what you'd asked for, but you could potentially setup an automated service to install an extension on a device, query its information, then uninstall it, which would only require permissions for your device and not the Chrome Web Store. Convoluted, yes, I know.

Comment: That function is deprecated. Use chrome.runtime.getManifest() instead